# How to access the localhost via android mobile device?

Tags: android, asp.net, localhost

I have a asp.net development server(localhost). I want to access the localhost through my android mobile phone(Sony Ericsson XPERIA). Because I have some web service methods that I want to access. I have done it using the emulator(by giving 10.0.2.2:portNo). But I don't know how to access the localhost via the mobile device.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Update: - 14-09-2012

Guyz I really need your help on this issue.....please help me..                          I have a wireless router and my laptop is connected to that, and also my laptop has a static ip given to it.
I have an android phone and it also connected to the wireless router perfectly.                                                                 And my web site is hosted in IIS7 and it is assigned with a port. 
What I need is to access the web services resides in the web site through my android device(using the application).
I have attempted many times giving laptop IP(static IP) and 10.0.2.2 IP also. But none works. And I am really confused now.
If you know any complete tutorials or if you did this before please post it. Your help on this is really appreciated guyz.  (please ignore my English if its wrong)                                                       Thank you.

Comment: are you connecting your device via WiFi ?

Comment: @ Lucifer: yes. I am connecting my device via wifi.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to **change the path** that you have given while accessing your
  **Web Service**.
- *Replace* **localhost** by your own **ip address**.
- You can fetch your **ip address** through **cmd**.
- goto **cmd** and type **ipconfig**.

Comment: @ Androider : didn't work for me, friend. It gave me a server unreachable error.... I gave IPAddress(got via ipconfig):portNo to my android application.

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile phone and your web server are on the same WiFi network, you can do as was suggested in other comments - figure out the IP address of your development server using the ipconfig command and then use that address on your phone.  Note that you may need to modify the firewall settings on your development server to allow incoming connections.

However, if your mobile phone is on 3G or the devices are just not on the same network, things get more complicated because you probably do not have a public IP on your development server and the devices won't be able to see each other.

In that case you either need to reconfigure your development server's local router (google for instructions on "port forwarding") or use a tool like https://pagekite.net/ (disclaimer: I wrote that!) to give your development server presence on the public Internet.

Good luck!

Comment: Runar: I gave the IP address assigned by the wifi router to laptop(got through ipconfig) and use that address(in web browser) on my android device but as I said in the above comment it did not work. It gave me a server unreachable error. And please tell me how to modify the firewall settings on the development server to allow incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

Simply visit 10.0.2.2 in your Android-browser. If this does'nt work, disable your firewall aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your Android Device ( Phone or Tablet ) via **WiFi** Connection with your local network.

Once the connection is establish, you can check the connection in browser by opening url `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:portNo` ( as answer by EvdTempel )

Comment: @ Lucifer: I tried what you have told me to do so. But it did not connect to my development server(asp.net) via my android device. I gave 10.0.2.2:portNo and also I have tried the IP address:portNo given by wifi router to my laptop, but nothing works. It gives the server unreachable error on the android device web browser. please help me.

Comment: i think your companies firewall is blocking you from request, contact the network admin and ask him to help you in opening the page in android device by allowing through firewall.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set address as "10.0.2.2:**portNr**"

**portNr** = the given port by ASP.NET Development Server

Answer (score -1):

Hey I had the same issue and resolved it form the information I found at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1109558

use the 4 answer "4. Re: How to access localhost on ASP.NET Website from Android device"

worked for me :)

Comment: You might want to include the relevant pieces of code from your linked webpage as if it changes/moves in the future your answer will be invalid.

Comment: Can't look at the webpage and the answer only provides this link.

Answer (score -2):

Simply visit `http://your-system-ip-address/your-site` name.
If it does not work then disable your firewall as well.